# vim NERDTree unable to open file

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I install NERDTree plugin in my vim. Attaching my vimrc file

```
set wildmenu
set relativenumber
syntax on
set ruler
set smarttab
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
call plug#end()
map <C-n> :NERDTree<cr>
```

I am having a problem.

when i open a file structure shown below

```
test
    /app
        /2.txt 
    1.txt

cd test
ls -l 
rw-r--r-- 1 vipin vipin    2 Apr  1 02:11 1.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 vipin vipin 4096 Apr  1 02:11 app

ls -l app/
-rw-r--r-- 1 vipin vipin 2 Apr  1 02:11 2.txt
```

i pressed  C and cd in test folder.

After the above command able to open 1.txt without any issue with enter command. But unable to open 2.txt with enter.

I am very new to VIM. Please guide me what mistake i am doing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to Open the .vimrc file add

```
set encoding=utf-8
```

Thanks all for the assistance.